# Spring Eureka App doesn't show dashboard

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix-eureka

There is a Eureka Server application:

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class RegistrationModulesServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegistrationModulesServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

With applicaton.yml config (be default):

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client: 
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

server:
  port: 1111
```

On the first run - I saw dashboard with statuses.
Like in documentation:
[image]

Then - after restart I can see only xml response:
[image]

Why?

No error in log.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. did you find a workaround?

Comment: I agree with @quqtalk. If you configured it is as web project templates and static folders would have been created under resources. Unless you don't need them, just delete "static" and "templates" folders

Answer (score 8):

I encounter the exact same issue, after long time investigation, just:
delete the folder "templates" and "static" from /src/main/resources

Answer (score 5):

For me, the issue was that I had an empty folder, src/main/resources/templates. When this folder exists, FreeMarkerView cannot see the embedded templates contained in spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server. I don't remember where this folder originated but I suspect it is in the online sample.

Comment: This solved it for me; you have to clean the project after deleting the `templates` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this spring boot / cloud versions:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent> 

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and maybe setting environment

```
eureka:
  environment: dev
```

There is a full example in [this github project](https://github.com/mariocuellar1/eureka-server)

Answer (score 0):

It was also not working for me, then I made some changes in my pom.xml and then it worked

**Non working pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample.eurekaserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EurekaServer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud</description>

    <parent> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**After changing above pom.xml to below one, it worked**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample.eurekaserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EurekaServer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Angel.SR6</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <requiresUnpack>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
              <artifactId>eureka-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
              <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
          </requiresUnpack>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <appName>${heroku.appName}</appName>
          <includeTarget>false</includeTarget>
          <includes>
            <include>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

May this will help

**--Edit--**
my application.yml file looks like:

```
server:
  port: 8010

eureka:  
  instance:
    hostname: localhost    
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. It happens because of corrupt jars or version mismatch. Please delete all the jars from the maven m2 repository in your local (i.e. c:/User/m2).

It should work then.